# Problemas ao criar um sistema de login com PHP e MySQLi

Tags: php

Estou tentando fazer um sistema de login e cadastro de usuários em PHP, mas estou com vários problemas somente no login.php, o cadastro tá funcionando corretamente, mas o login está apresentando os erros: **Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\wamp\www\rifa\login.php on line 13** e **Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\wamp\www\rifa\login.php on line 14**, o meu código está logo abaixo, alguém tem uma ideia de como eu posso corrigir estes erros?

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE & ~ E_DEPRECATED);
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '12345';
$db = 'rifou';

$connection = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password);
mysqli_select_db($connection, $db);
$nickname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['nick']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['senha']);
$select_user = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nick='$nickname' AND senha='$senha'";
$run_user = mysqli_query($con, $select_user);
$check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);
if ($check_user > 0){
    echo "logado";
} else {
   echo "não logado";
}
?>
```

Comment: Sua conexão não é válida.

Comment: Como assim? O código não consegue se conectar ao db?

Comment: Quando eu editei meu código para o descrito em http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp ele funcionou perfeitamente, mas não do jeito que eu quero.

Comment: Faça da seguinte forma no select, utilize o parametro mysqli_query, e chame a variavel $connection em primeiro lugar.

Answer (score 2):

Observa que no seu código foi declarada a seguinte linha:

```
$connection = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password);
```

Mais abaixo você declarou:

```
$run_user = mysqli_query($con, $select_user);
```

A variável $con não existe pois você a criou com o nome de $connection.
Sendo assim cabe a você mudar o nome da variável $connection para $con ou $con para $connection.

Answer (score 1):

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

Sua conexão não é válida, segundo o erro. Sua variável de conexão é `$connection` e não `$con`(que está na chamada de `mysqli_query()`.

```
$connection = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password);
mysqli_select_db($connection, $db);
//Linhas omitidas
$run_user = mysqli_query($con, $select_user); //<--- deve $connection e não $con
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['senha']);
$select_user = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nick='$nickname' AND senha='$senha'";
```

você declarou a variável como "$password" sendo que na hora de conferir na tabela você colou "$senha" uma variável que não exite